# show discount percent of product in Text Widget in flutter

Tags: flutter, text, discount

I want to show amount of discount percent in Text widget in flutter, i used the Discount calculation formula but it didn't worked , How can i do that?
this is what i want:

```
Container(
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
  color: Color(0xfff40725),
  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50),
),

child: Padding(
  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
  child: Text(
    '50% (but with formula',
    style: TextStyle(
      color: Colors.white, 
      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
    ),
  ),
),
```

Comment: you can calculate using formula in any variable and then print in text widget with the help of toString method.

Comment: No , It's static text i want show the percent by formula, For example like this:

Text((old_price-new-price)/new-price*100);

Comment: (Data to found the percent * 100) / Sum of your all data
e.g [3,7,1] i want to find the percent of 7
(7*100) / 3+7+1

Comment: can you show me with sample ? pskink

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use string substitution.

```dart
Text("${your_formula()}%")
```

Comment: Thanks but where i can use the formula?
when i try to defined it , i got this error:
Only static members can be accessed in initializers, what does this mean?

Comment: I think I'd need to see more code to be able to help you with this. See here for how it works: https://dartpad.dev/953579e821cc2c5ddebee07e4fe0894f